# Using only greek fonts from a certain fonts package

Tags: fonts

I am fairly new to LaTex, and I want to use a different font family for greeks (and leave all the other letters unaffected such as ordinary alphabets).

In particular, I want to use GFS Bodoni package's greek fonts, but I want to keep everything else in Computer Modern.

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the kernel function `\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{LGR}{\rmdefault}{bodoni}

\begin{document}
This is English

\textgreek{Πάτερ ἡμῶν ὁ ἐν τοῖς οὐρανοῖς·}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The only difficult bit, after having realized that a font substitution is needed, is finding the font family name. Then a simple

```
texdoc gfsbodoni.sty
```

from the terminal, reveals the lines

```
\DeclareOption{default}{%
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bodoni}}
```

so we found what we were looking for.

The most useful Greek font families for this purpose are `artemisia`, `bodoni`, `udidot`, `gfsbaskerville`.

Note: see edit history for a previous solution using the substitutefont package, now declared obsolete.

Comment: You are a fount of knowledge!  Or is that "font of knowledge"??