# Keeping only the \mathcal fonts from the CM fonts package?

Tags: fonts

So thanks to may resourceful people of TeX exchange, I managed to change the greek fonts only to Bodoni, and math font for times.

But there is no end to human desire and... now I want to use the math calligraphic (math cal) fonts from the CM modern package.

So I am looking for something \Declaremathfont, except that it is only for the calligraphic letters.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example showing the code you are currently using to configure your fonts. Otherwise, any answer provided is liable either not to work or to have unintended side-effects. There is, by the way, no 'CM modern package'. CM is what you get when you don't load any packages at all.

Comment: And there is no `\Declaremathfont` that I know of....

Answer (score 2):

*Don't try this at home...*

Mixing fonts in this way is ***not*** recommended and is likely to produce results which are significantly suboptimal.

However, if you really must:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathcal{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\mathcal{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
```

[image: font mishmash]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,british]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{bodoni}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathcal{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\mathcal{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
This is English

\textgreek{Πάτερ ἡμῶν ὁ ἐν τοῖς οὐρανοῖς·}

$\mathcal{ABC}$

\end{document}
```

Based on [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237143/) to your earlier question. I can't find the code you are using for Times so I've guessed but it shouldn't matter.

[EDITED to simplify thanks to egreg's comment.]

Comment: could you tell me as to *why* it is a bad idea to mix fonts, and the result arising from it is significantly suboptimal? By the way, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @user134070 The usual advice is to use fonts from a single family or, at most, to use, say, a sans font for headings etc. and a matching serif for the body of the document. Mixing different serifs or different sans fonts in the same document tends not to look good. Moreover, even if the fonts are sufficiently similar to work well together, this is likely true only when one or other is appropriately scaled. Otherwise, the font dimensions will differ. In maths mode, especially, layout is highly dependent on a number of font dimensions - even more than text. It is not terrible necessarily...

Comment: @user134070 if it is just `\mathcal` but you appear to be mixing a Times clone, a Bodoni, some things from Computer Modern and I'm not clear what else. You say you are using Times for maths. I'm assuming (hoping) you are using it for text as well. Basically too many disparate elements is distracting and tends to look not very nice. Different fonts have different levels of greyness in that a page of text in one will be more or less grey than a page of text in another. If you mix those fonts, the difference leaps out from the page. Even if you are careful, too many fonts spoil the broth.

Comment: Why not simply `\DeclareMathAlphabet`?

Comment: @egreg Because I copied it from `fontmath.ltx`....

Comment: @cfr The difference is that a symbol font is allocated a math group no matter whether it's used or not, which is not the case for a math alphabet. In the particular case it's not very relevant, it could be in other cases.