# Borrowing only Greek fonts from ebgaramond font family

Tags: fonts

I asked a similar question in the past, namely, I wanted to just use the Bodoni font for the greek letters.

Now I need to use ebgaramond font family, but my effort to follow the answer to my old question did not prove to be fruitful...

The suggested answer was to use substitutefont package, but changing bodoni to ebgaramond does not seem to work... Please help!

My old question: [Using only greek fonts from a certain fonts package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237140/using-only-greek-fonts-from-a-certain-fonts-package)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see the `ebgaramond` package does not provide the font in LGR encoding. If you are willing to use `xelatex` or `lualatex`, you can do this easily using the original OpenType font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{EB Garamond}[Script=Greek]
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
This is English

\textgreek{Πάτερ ἡμῶν ὁ ἐν τοῖς οὐρανοῖς·}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`pdffonts` gives:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
BECQJC+LMRoman10-Regular-Identity-H  CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
RXOBML+EBGaramond12-Regular-Identity-H CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      7  0
```